# How to comparing binary numbers in C++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I want to compare binary digits by xor

Ex:
bin1: 1011
bin2: 0011

result: 1000 ==> (bin1[0] != bin2[0], bin1[1] == bin2[1], bin1[2] == bin2[2], bin1[3] == bin2[3])

My Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    int bin;
    int vec1[bin];
    int vec2[bin];
    int a;

    cin>>n;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        cin>>bin;
        for(int j=0;j<bin;j++) {
            cin>>vec1[j];
            cin>>vec2[j];
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<bin;j++) {
            if(vec1[j]==vec2[j]) {
                a = 0;
            } else if (vec1[j]!=vec2[j]) {
                a = 1;
            }
        cout<<a<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it 'XOR' ?  `bin1 ^ bin2`

Comment: Are you looking for operator `&&`?

Comment: What are the types of `bin1` and `bin2`?

Comment: Gonna take some code to (a) get the digits, (b) compare the digits, and (c) produce your output. An attempt, at least, on *all* of those should be in your question. If you tried, post your [mcve] and perhaps we can see where things went wrong. If you haven't tried... then.. its time to try.

Comment: `bin1` and `bin2` integer

Comment: Then what on earth does `bin1[0]` mean???

Comment: I use looping for this problem, `bin1[0]` just for representation from my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the XOR operator.
A^B = 0 if, A = B.
XOR gives 1 output if the inputs are not alike and 0 if they are alike.

So, if the answer is 0 for the XOR operation, you have equal numbers, otherwise not.
Of course, there are other ways like having them into different formats and then comparing using applicable comparison operators or functions.